# BOX2D static body friction

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, cocoa-touch, box2d

I am creating a ground body like this:

```
    // Define the ground body.
    b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
    groundBodyDef.position.Set(0, 0); // bottom-left corner

    // Call the body factory which allocates memory for the ground body
    // from a pool and creates the ground box shape (also from a pool).
    // The body is also added to the world.
    b2Body* groundBody = world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);

    // Define the ground box shape.
    b2PolygonShape groundBox;   

    // bottom
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(screenSize.width/PTM_RATIO,0));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox,0);

    // top
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,screenSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(screenSize.width/PTM_RATIO,screenSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox,0);

    // left
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,screenSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(0,0));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox,0);

    // right
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(screenSize.width/PTM_RATIO,screenSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(screenSize.width/PTM_RATIO,0));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox,0);
```

How can I set it's friction?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create fixture from fixture definition (b2FixtureDef) where you can set particular friction. Something like this:

```
b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;

fixtureDef.shape = &groundBox;
fixtureDef.density = 0.0f;
fixtureDef.friction = YOUR_FRICTION_VALUE;

groundBody->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
```

Comment: Did that and I am getting a semantic issue: 
/HelloWorldLayer.mm: error: Semantic Issue: Assigning to 'const b2Shape *' from incompatible type 'b2BodyDef *'

Comment: I've edited my answer, now it should work. You may also refer to Box2D documentation: http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082968